# mount failed, errno is 20?

Tags: linux, mount

I'm newbie in linux program. why following code failed? its output is "failed 20". 
but in terminal the command: *sudo mount /dev/sdb /home/abc/work/tmp* works.

```
void main()
{
    int rtn;

    rtn=mount("/dev/sdb","/home/abc/work/tmp","vfat",MS_BIND,"");  
    if (rtn==-1)
        printf("failed %d.\n",errno);
    else
        printf("OK!\n");
}
```

Comment: When you say "linux program", do you mean C language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 20 is ENOTDIR (http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html).

I think with MS_BIND, you would need the first argument to be an actual directory somewhere, not a device. See also [the man page for mount](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mount)

What you are trying to do would be equivalent to `sudo mount --bind /dev/sdb /home/abc/work/temp` which will give you an error too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind-mount a device, only a directory. Try providing a useful value for `mountflags`.

Answer (score 0):

You should print out not just the errno value, but also the corresponding error message:

```
printf("failed %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
```

This should reveal the reason for the problem. ("Not a directory", so `/home/abc/work/tmp` does not seem to be a directory.)

(There are various other problems with your code, such as missing `#include` statements, and writing error messages to stdout and not stderr, but those are irrelevant to your problem at hand. You can fix them later.)